# Python to C Sharp Regex pattern to repair json

Tags: c#, python, regex, json

I have a hardware device which is controlled via http with json strings, but the json it returns is known to be invalid.  In Python, I can repair it with

```
response = """[
{text: "67239961", selected: "true", value: "67239961"}
];"""
p = re.compile('([a-zA-Z_]+):')
joined = "".join(response.splitlines())
stripped = joined.strip(';')
cleaned = p.sub(r'"\1":', stripped)
>> [{"text": "67239961", "selected": "true", "value": "67239961"}]
```

I need do this in C Sharp, though, and am not familiar enough with its Regex implementations.  I have tried to directly port it as

```
string[] split = response.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string joined = String.Join("", split);
string stripped = joined.Trim(';');
Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z_]+):");
string cleaned = re.Replace(stripped, @"\1");
>> [{\1 "67239961", \1 "true", \1"67239961"}]
```

What would the correct pattern be to accomplish this?

Edit: the fix was

```
string cleaned = re.Replace(stripped, @"""$1"":");
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with regex in C#, but you can try to use `$1` instead of `\1`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that left the text, but removed the colon.  I also changed to Regex re = new Regex(@"\\([a-zA-Z_]+\\):"); and it left it the same as it started with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Newtonsoft JSON package, you don't have to resort to RegEx.

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Then in your code:

```
var str = @"[
{text: ""67239961"", selected: ""true"", value: ""67239961""}
];";

var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Replace(";",string.Empty));
var clean = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
```

Result will be:

```
[{"text":"67239961","selected":"true","value":"67239961"}]
```

If you truly have beginning and ending quotes, use this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
    str.Replace(";",string.Empty).Replace("\"[","[").Replace("]\"","]"));
```